# Colors not showing up in Javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, colors

I have been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLpjfr7mgT0I About making a game with Javascript. I wanted to test it out in my wepbage, but the canvas has no colors, even though it should have a border and a black rectangle. I don't know what should i do, so i hope someone could help me fix this code so it works in my wepbage. Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<head>

<canvas id = "canvas" width = "640" height = "480">
style = "border:1px solid gray; width: 640px; height: 480px;">
</canvas>

<script>
var Context = {
    canvas : null,
    context : null,
    create: function(canvas_tag_id) {
        this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_tag_id);
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        return this.context;
    }

};

$(document.ready(function){


   Context.create("canvas");

   Context.context.beginPath(); 
   Context.context.rect(0, 0, 640, 480);
   Context.context.fillStyle = 'black';
   Context.context.fill();

   // Context.context.beginPath();



});
</head>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found like 6-7 differents errors, most of them are bad balise imbrication/position problems and you had not event include jQuery in your script...

Here a working example, try to compare it with your code to understand what was wrong.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
  <canvas id = "canvas" width = "640" height = "480" style = "border:1px solid gray; width: 640px; height: 480px;">
  </canvas>

  <script>
    var Context = {
      canvas : null,
      context : null,
      create: function(canvas_tag_id) {
        this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_tag_id);
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d'); 
        return this.context;
      }
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
      Context.create("canvas");
      Context.context.beginPath();
      Context.context.rect(0, 0, 640, 480);
      Context.context.fillStyle = 'black';
      Context.context.fill();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly now!

Comment: Just to add: if you don't intend to use jQuery you can use native javascript like this to wait for the DOM to load: `window.onload=function(){ ...your javascript here... }`